# spring websockets: sending a message to an offline user - messages not enqueued in message broker

Tags: java, spring, websocket, activemq-classic, spring-websocket

I have a webapp with spring and websockets using a message broker (activemq).

here is my config class:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
@EnableScheduling
public class WebSocketConfig extends AbstractWebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {

@Override
public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry config) {
    config.enableStompBrokerRelay("/topic","/queue/");
    config.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app");
 }

@Override
public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
    registry.addEndpoint("/hello").withSockJS();
 }

}
```

I have a scheduled task that constantly pushing messages to the username "StanTheMan" :

```
@Scheduled(fixedDelay = 1000)
public void sendGreetings() {
   HelloMessage hello = new HelloMessage();
   hello.setContent("timeStamp:" + System.currentTimeMillis());
   String queueMapping = "/queue/greetings";    
   template.convertAndSendToUser(
                     "DannyD",
                     queueMapping,
                     hello);

}
```

Currently, if the user is NOT connected via a websocket to the server - all the messages for him are **not** being en-queued for him, they simply **discarded**. whenever he connects - fresh messages **are** being en-queued for him.
Is it possible for me to "convertAndSendToUser" a message to an offline user in any way? i would like to en-queue messages with an expired time for offline users to be later on pushed when they are connecting again and the expired time wasn't over.

how can i achieve that? Obviously using a real message broker (activemq) supposed to help achieving that, but how?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

Indeed this feature can only be used to send messages to a (presently) connected user.

We plan to provide better ways to track failed messages (see [SPR-10891](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-10891)). In the meantime as a workaround you could inject the `UserSessionRegistry` into your @Scheduled component and check if the getSessionIds methods returns a non-empty Set. That would indicate the user is connected.

One alternative may be to use your own convention for a queue name that each user can subscribe to (probably based on their user name or something else that's unique enough) in order to receive persistent messages. The [ActiveMQ STOMP page](http://activemq.apache.org/stomp.html) has a section on persistent messages and expiration times.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. If i'm using the alternative you suggested (a queue for each user with persistance) - I've noticed that each user can subscribe to each other user he like (no security measure is involved). So I created a "ChannelInterceptor" to verify the same username is the name of the queue. is that a legitimately secured way to achieve this?

Comment: Yes registering an interceptor on the "clientInboundChannel" is the right place for something like this. It intercepts all messages right after they're parsed and before any other message handling takes place.

Comment: > "One alternative may be to use your own convention for a queue name that each user can subscribe to (probably based on their user name or something else that's unique enough)"   
---

The problem of using this technique is that the queues are public and a client can subscribe to /prefix/* thus getting message sent to all the other users.

Answer (score -1):

This is a default behavior for message brokers. 
And you haven't setup the ActiveMQ broker as your default broker so Spring is setting up a in-memory broker.

To achieve what you want setup/give your details of activeMQ to your spring websocket message broker. As Spring doesn't provide these settings, you have to do all the persistence settings at the ActiveMQ side. .

To setup ActiveMQ for spring websocket message broker you also need to enable stomp and  use this:

```
registry.enableStompBrokerRelay("/topic").setRelayHost("hostName").setRelayPort("00000");
```

For more information checkout:
http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.0.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/messaging/simp/config/StompBrokerRelayRegistration.html

Comment: I did use an activemq broker and its actually working. problem was is that sending messages to offline users is not enqueued for them to be later consumed when they are connecting again.

Comment: You haven't shown your application context or complete configuration; Are you using all Java config or a mix of Java and XML config ?

Comment: You can't setup a custom broker without the above line in my answer. And also if you edit your answer write the new lines at the end of your question don't just change it. Thanks

Comment: Alir - I already posted the WebSocketConfig. my other configurations are xml based but they are irrelevant for the websocket mechanism. in any case my line:  config.enableStompBrokerRelay("/topic","/queue/");  is pretty much equivalent to the line you suggested.

Comment: @Urbanleg :) all the best for finding a solution. It seems you can't see the solution infront of you. Just to clarify if you still don't get it --- Spare some time and see what .setRelayHost does in the link above. Since you are configuring websocket through Java config there is no way your ActiveMQ can be connected to the configuration you have given in your Question. Thanks again for the downvote. Cheers

Comment: Alir - I will upvote and grant you the points if needed, but as far as my checking goes, my activemq running and actually creates new queues and enqueue the messages as excpected.  just for you to know: config.enableSimpleBroker VS config.enableStompBrokerRelay  the first one is like you said creates an in memory broker that spring supplies, the latter is activemq broker.